# automapper proxy base type

Tags: automapper, castle-dynamicproxy

how can I set BaseTypeForInterfaceProxy on Automapper.

Comment: http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/04/15/automapper-feature-interfaces-and-dynamic-mapping/